# give Image of UItabbar Item, Using storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am not able to give colourful Image of UItabbar Item, Using storyboards.Please help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `CustomTabbarController` in your project and set your TabBarController Class `CustomTabbarController` , This will work for you.

```
#import "CustomTabbarController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation CustomTabbarController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    ThirdViewController *third = [[ThirdViewController alloc]init];


    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, third, nil]];  

    UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-active.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star-active.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search-active.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"]; 

    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]; 

    [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
}

@end
```

Comment: If this help you then mark the answer correct for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Tabbar for that.

Hope it is helpful to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can not do it in storyboard.

Right now storyboard support only icon kind of tint image.

But you can set any image you want to set by code.

If you dont have idea for code and want some help than comment I may help.